# Python: How to get the updated dictionary in 1 line?

Tags: python, dictionary

In python, I have a dictionary named dict_a :

```
dict_a = {'a':1}
```

and I want to get a new dictionary `dict_b` as the update of `dict_a`,at the same time I don't want to change the `dict_a`, so I used this:

```
dict_b = copy.deepcopy(dict_a).update({'b':2})
```

However,  the return value of `dict.update` is `None`, so the above code doesn't work. And I have to use this：

```
temp = copy.deepcopy(dict_a)
temp.update({'b':2})
dict_b = temp
```

The question is, how to get my goal in one line? Or some

Comment: `temp = copy.deepcopy(dict_a); temp.update({'b':2}); dict_b = temp`

Comment: You could just use `dict.copy()` :

    dict_b = dict_a.copy()
    dict_b.update({'b':1})

Comment: Use `toolz.merge([dict_a, {'b': 2}])` http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.dicttoolz.merge

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
>>> a = {'a':1}
>>> update = {'b': 1}
>>> b = dict(a.items() + update.items())
>>> b
{'a': 1, 'b': 1}
```

`update` -  is your value that need to update(extend) dict `a`

`b` - is a new resulting dict

Anfd in this case `a` stay unchanged

Comment: I still wondering how to get the results of `copy.deepcopy(dict_a).update({'b':2})`, the results seems disappeared somehow.

Comment: @springcc you can also do `a = {'a':1}; b = {'b':2}; {k: v for d in [a, b] for k, v in d.items()}`